# RegionInfo all properties populated with ISO code in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, cultureinfo, regioninfo

any ideas why in Blazor when I try to get user country name from RegionInfo all properties have the ISO code assigned?

```
///User.Country = "DE"
RegionInfo region = new RegionInfo(User.Country);
_country = region.EnglishName;
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using NET 8?

Comment: nope, still on .NET 7

Comment: Blazor supports a limited api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu#icu-on-webassembly